# Centering Problems

Tags: html, css

Okay, so I just started a basic template for a website and I'm already running into an issue with centering.

I have a big box that I want to cover MOST of the website with a little room on every side, and I just want it to hang centered in the website.

Problem is, I set the position to relative and the thing disappears, I set it to absolute and the thing shows up but isn't centered of course. I'm just wondering why the box disappears when I'm setting it to relative, when it should be relative to the body.

Here's all the code, it's not much as I'm just starting this template

HTML:

```
<div class="bigbox">

</div>
```

CSS:

```
* {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}

body{
    background-color:#212121;   
}

.bigbox{
    background-color:red;
    height:90%;
    width:90%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    position:relative;
    z-index:1;
    float:left;
}
```

Thanks for taking a look, I'm sure it's a retarded easy fix

Comment: why is this getting downvoted? I'm new to this site but I thought this was a place to get help? If my formatting is wrong please tell me so I can fix it I'd rather receive the knowledge I need to make this work then get downvoted?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can achieve what you want in various ways:

**vertical height (vh unit)**: https://jsfiddle.net/arthurcamara/bjhrz9n9/

```css
*
{
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}

body{
    background-color:#212121;

}

.bigbox{
    background-color:red;
    height:90vh;
    width:90%;
    margin: 5vh auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="bigbox"></div>
```

**absolute positioniong**: https://jsfiddle.net/arthurcamara/bjhrz9n9/1/

```css
body{
    background-color:#212121;

}

.bigbox{
    background-color:red;
    position: absolute;
    top: 5%;
    right: 5%;
    left: 5%;
    bottom: 5%;
}
```

```html
<div class="bigbox"></div>
```

and my favorite **flexbox**: https://jsfiddle.net/arthurcamara/bjhrz9n9/2/

```css
body{
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color:#212121;
  
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.bigbox{
    background-color:red;
    width: 90%;
    height: 90%;
}
```

```html
<div class="bigbox"></div>
```

Answer (score 3):

I guess your problem is the percentage height in combination of an unknown height of the body. You should add a height to the body like in the following example:

```
html, body {
    height: 100%;
}
```

[Working JFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ku0z31Lc/1/)

Comment: thanks, wasn't aware the body tags needed height or width value I guess I thought they just defaulted to fill whatever resolution they are sitting in.

Comment: The body by default always has the size of the elements inside it. A percentage height requires the body to have an 100% height set. Glad it helped.

Comment: Update, 

This did not work, I applied height and width values to the body and still no big box div appears

Comment: change the body selector to `html, body { ... }`. This will make it work.

Comment: the problem here is that it's not vertically centered.

Comment: [Here](http://codepen.io/chriscoyier/pen/lpema) is an example of vertical centering on block elements.

Answer (score 1):

The problem occurs, because the box has no fixed height. So you need to set the height for `body` and `html` to `100%`

```css
* {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}
html {
  height: 100%;
}
body {
  background-color: #212121;
  height: 100%;
}
.bigbox {
  background-color: red;
  height: 90%;
  width: 90%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<div class="bigbox">

</div>
```

Comment: Thank you, this worked. I guess it is stupid to assume the html and body tags default to fill the screen as scrolling is a thing. 

Thanks!

Comment: @GageLovett You just have to remove `float: left` from `.bigbox`. After doing that, the box should be horizontal centered.

Answer (score 0):

First up add a width to the div. You could do it in any format `px`, `%`, `vw` etc.

```
div{
  width: 80%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The following should give you what you are looking for. You can adjust the border by changing the html, body height percent and the .bigbox margins.

```css
html, body {
  height: 98%;
}

body{
  background-color:#212121;

}


.bigbox{
  background-color:red;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 15px 5px;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<div class="bigbox">

</div>
```